# How to string format in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a new python learner, I want to ask a question about string format.

```
a = 3
len = 5
```

I want to format a as a binary number and the number length is 5. So I want to format it to '00011'.

How can I do in python?

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = format(a,'b').zfill(len)
```

Comment: Isn't it sort of counter-productive to ask if an answer is the best one *when attempting to answer another question*?

Comment: @zondo I'm sorry. As a new user in stack overflow, I have made some mistakes.